# Django getting error exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, uppy

**Info**: I want to upload files using [Uppy](https://uppy.io/docs/) in frontend and [django-tus](https://github.com/alican/django-tus) as backend for file processing. I am getting error `TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException`.

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /tus/upload/6393bfe5-277e-4c68-b9af-c0394be796b9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/django_tus/tusfile.py", line 75, in get_tusfile_or_404
    raise TusResponse(status=404)
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
[06/Aug/2022 14:36:42] "HEAD /tus/upload/6393bfe5-277e-4c68-b9af-c0394be796b9 HTTP/1.1" 500 103054
[06/Aug/2022 14:36:42,624] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 35814)

[06/Aug/2022 14:36:42] "POST /tus/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 201 0
[06/Aug/2022 14:36:42] "PATCH /tus/upload/8295bef4-c94a-4ab7-9c75-2635c74428d8 HTTP/1.1" 204 0
```

https://github.com/alican/django-tus/blob/master/django_tus/tusfile.py

```py
class TusUpload(View):

    def head(self, request, resource_id):
        tus_file = TusFile.get_tusfile_or_404(str(resource_id))

        return TusResponse(
            status=200,
            extra_headers={
                'Upload-Offset': tus_file.offset,
                'Upload-Length': tus_file.file_size,
            })
```

```py
def create_initial_file(metadata, file_size: int):
        resource_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        cache.add("tus-uploads/{}/filename".format(resource_id), "{}".format(metadata.get("filename")), settings.TUS_TIMEOUT)
        cache.add("tus-uploads/{}/file_size".format(resource_id), file_size, settings.TUS_TIMEOUT)
        cache.add("tus-uploads/{}/offset".format(resource_id), 0, settings.TUS_TIMEOUT)
        cache.add("tus-uploads/{}/metadata".format(resource_id), metadata, settings.TUS_TIMEOUT)

        tus_file = TusFile(resource_id)
        tus_file.write_init_file()
        return tus_file
```

Comment: Do not use the [tag:git] or [tag:github] tags simply because you're using a Git repository on GitHub. This is a basic Python programming error: you are trying to create an exception but not using the BaseException class as your base class. (This constraint was not enforced in old versions of Python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Our [pull request](https://github.com/alican/django-tus/commit/56ceb636f3c0cf9bd855d85f3a8d3b84519dc7f2) has now fixed this error.

The django-tus attempts in case of 404 error raise [in line 60](https://github.com/alican/django-tus/blob/cc2b6bfb993f383bf81ea2701bdc20e4c183347e/django_tus/tusfile.py#L69) [`TusResponse`](https://github.com/alican/django-tus/blob/aacdaf6deca0a9f2b76a74dafa748cd4e88b667e/django_tus/response.py) which does not however inherit from exception.

This is an error of the library. It has not been updated in 2 years and according to the @torek `BaseException` inheritance was not previously enforced. You could try to wrap it in try-except with `TypeError` but in my implementation this does not work.

You could attempt to add `BaseException` to inherited classes of `TusResponse` in your version of django-tus.

```py
class TusResponse(HttpResponse, BaseException):
```

which should remove the error.